# An error occurred with app. Please try again later

Tags: facebook

i am getting An error occurred with app name. Please try again later.
my app id ,secret id and redirect url is correct still am getting this error

my code is this

```
<?php
require $DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/temp/socialtest/src/facebook.php';
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(
    array(
      'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
      'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    )
);
// Get User ID

    $user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user)
{
    try
    {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if($user) 
{
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    echo $user_profile['id'];
    echo $user_profile['email'];
    echo $user_profile['user_birthday'];
    echo $user_proile['gender'];
}
else{
    $param = array();
    $param['scope'] = array('email');
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($param);
 echo "<a href='".$loginUrl."'><img src='fb-login-button.png'></a>";
}


?>
```

tell me where i am doing wrong
everything is fine there

ther problem is solved but now i want the auth box in popup how i can do that

Comment: Wont work in a local server as localhost. & check that you have the correct domain entered in your facebook app details.

Comment: ya the domain is correct in app

Answer (score -1):

> but now i want the auth box in popup how i can do that

By switching from server-side to client-side auth; embed the JavaScript SDK and call FB.login method.

And btw., contrary to gopi1410’s comment, it should work just fine on localhost too, for testing. Usually everything that takes place in your browser (JavaScript API calls, redirects, etc.) are no problem; only thing that you can’t test properly on localhost are cases where Facebook’s servers actually have to contact your server (deauth callback, extraction of OG meta content, …). And even that is possible to set up, if your make your development server available „over the internet”, via some dyndns service.

Comment: It's most likely they've forgotten to use the same redirect_uri value